# KDE spellchecker dropdown is empty

Tags: 14.04, kde, spell-checking, kile

i run Ubuntu 14.04, installed packages are kile, aspell-de and aspell-en, the problem is that the dropdowns for dictionaries are empty (or show "()"). Changing the spellchecker language in `~/.kde/share/config/kilerc` directly works, however. Is it a known bug?